# Overlap Images In Center [css]

Tags: css, image, html

I'm trying to overlap images in css. They are both aligned in the center but one is below the other one. I tried z-index'ing which is fine with position: absolute; but if I do that then I lose my centering.

Issue:
[image]

The dots are supposed to be over the phone.

My HTML:

```
<div class="content-top"><div class="cwrap">
        <motto>Become Famous On Vine.</motto>
        <img id="phone" src="./images/phone.png">
        <img id="dots" src="./images/dots.png">
    </div></div>
```

My CSS:

```
.cwrap {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 80%;
}

.content-top {
background-color: #00b589;
height: 650px;
width: 100%;
}

.content-top motto {
display: block;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 15px;
color: #FFF;
font-size: 60px;
font-family: "Source Sans Pro ExtraLight";
}

.content-top motto {
display: block;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 15px;
color: #FFF;
font-size: 60px;
font-family: "Source Sans Pro ExtraLight";
}

#phone {
z-index: 999;
}

#dots {
z-index: 1000;
}

.content-top img {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
position: relative;
display: block;
}
```

Comment: Can you rehost those images somewhere so I can add them to a fiddle?

Comment: @brbcoding You can do it with any 2 images, I'll get the gist. :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. **position: absolute;**, **top: 0;**, **left: 0;** 
The the red div is semi-transparent to reveal the blue div below.

Now, if you want to center these in the middle of the page, `<div class="container">` use css: **margin: 0 auto;**.

Link to example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enbs/Q4qNC/1/)

Comment: I would not suggest using absolute positioning. Anyhow, here is a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enbs/Q4qNC/2/).

Answer (score 2):

Use on #phone and #dots elements these css attributes: position, z-index, top, and left.

Use position: absolute the upper layer, and the top and left to place the upper layer to the correct location. Use z-index to specify the layer, lower value is backer, bigger value is upper.