# Overlapping 2 images without losing centering

Tags: html, css

I need to overlap two images that I centred using the following CSS:

```
display: block;
margin: auto;
```

The current situation is this-

[The current situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Uf6W.png)

I want the bigger image (the one at the bottom right now) to be under the smaller image and the text **without** losing the already centred positions. I've tried with `z-index` and setting the positions to `relative` and `absolute` but that just messes up with the alignment of the images.

HTML:

```
<img id="logo" src="Pics/logo1.png" class="animated bounceInUp">  
<img id="wall" src="Pics/Ywall1.png">
```

CSS:

```
#logo
{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 15%;
}

#wall
{
    height: 500px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Tried **this** answer also but again I got issues with alignment. Adjusting the `top` and `left` values is not only a big headache but it also doesn't give perfect centring.

**This:** [Overlap Images In Center [css]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18563582/overlap-images-in-center-css)

P.S- Stackoverflow won't let me embed images and embed 2 links until I get 10 rep. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to have the larger image as a background?

```css
#wall {
    height: 413px;
    width: 620px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-image: url('http://cdn2.spectator.co.uk/files/2016/07/wall.jpg');
    text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<div id="wall">
  <div>
      <img id="logo" src="https://logopond.com/avatar/1862/logoholik-icon-logopond2.png" class="animated bounceInUp"> 
      <div>Logo Text!</div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: That sir is a clever workaround. Works like a charm except for the fact that background-image: url(../Pics/Ywall1.png); does not load my background image. My HTML, CSS and Image both are stored in different directories inside the same folder.

Comment: Does 
background-image: url('/Pics/Ywall1.png');

Comment: But this still leaves the text hanging around... I also need the text exactly below my logo, and centered of course.

Comment: Editted answer to fix the logo text. Relative paths for background images shouldn't be too difficult. At worst give it an absolute path for now and fix that later.

Comment: This doesn't work. Note that my text isn't any regular text. I am using the typed.js plugin which displays this text. The actual text is placed in a div. The text that shows up is in a `span`. I tried putting the span inside a div into the div with the background but that didn't work. It shifted the logo to the left and the text came on the right both at the same height and **on** the background image.

Comment: The text needs to be in a block level container.